# Calculate source RGBA value from overlay

Tags: c#, rgba

The title looks a bit weird, so here is a sample:
You will probably be familiar with the Windows 7 Explorer.
When you select something with the pressed left mouse button, you get a blue half transparent rectangle.
So the question is now:
It is possible to calculate the source RGBA color that was used to draw this rectangle?
The only things I know is the RGB value from the background and the RGB value with the blue overlay. Here is a screenshot from what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, it ist not possible from a single image.
You need the target data over a black and a white image (best case).

After that, you need to use the first forumular in this article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing