# Calculate source RGBA given two samples composited over black and white backgrounds

Tags: algorithm, colors, alpha, alphablending

## Explanation

I have a semi-transparent color of *unknown value*.

I have a sample of this unknown color composited over a *black background* and another sample over a *white background*.

**How do I find the RGBA value of the unknown color?**

---

## Example

***Note:*** RGB values of composites are calculated using formulas from the [Wikipedia article on alpha compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)

### Composite over black:

`rgb(103.5, 32.5, 169.5)`

[image: Composite over black]

### Composite over white:

`rgb(167.25, 96, 233.25)`

[image: Composite over white]

### Calculated value of unknown color will be:

`rgba(138, 43, 226, 0.75)`

[image: Calculated color value]

---

## What I've Read

- [Manually alpha blending an RGBA pixel with an RGB pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014729/manually-alpha-blending-an-rgba-pixel-with-an-rgb-pixel)
- [Calculate source RGBA value from overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618332/calculate-source-rgba-value-from-overlay)

Comment: Not possible.  Look at your values.  The one on black ends up lighter than the one on white.

Comment: Alphas still look way off for the different values.

Comment: @stark See if my new example is any clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some experimentation, but I think I figured it out.

Subtracting any of the color component values between the black and white composite should give you the inverse of the original color's alpha value, eg:

```
A_original = 1 - ((R_white_composite - R_black_composite) / 255) // in %, 0.0 to 1.0
```

It should yield the same value whether you use the R, G, or B component. Now that you have the original alpha, finding the new components is as easy as:

```
R_original = R_black_composite / A_original
G_original = G_black_composite / A_original
B_original = B_black_composite / A_original
```